# Using MVC Controller to Save Data from Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller

I have developed an MVC Application in C#. I now have a requirement to expose Web Services (API) for other internal systems and later other external systems to invoke the API.

I have gone ahead an implemented a new WCF Project in the same solution as the MVC Application.  There is no issue getting a sample request and response from the WCF Web Service.

The solution that I would like to follow is to use the same business logic layer for all sources.  The Business Logic Layer currently sits within the MVC application, and have a decency on the ModelState to validate and finally save new/modified records using Entity Framework.

Due to this dependency on the ModelState, I cannot simply invoke the Service Layer without the ModelState which of course belongs to MVC.

I created an MVC Controller which would act as my gateway between the Business Layer, and the WCF Layer.  No matter what I do, cannot call an Action directly in the Controller.  The Controller inherits from the Controller class, which seems to have protected the Controller, as not to be able to instantiate it as an Object from the WCF Layer.

I've tried:

```
    APITransactionController controller = new APITransactionController();
```

I get an error, which I cannot get around:

```
Error   CS0122  'APITransactionController.APITransactionController()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Also tried:

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<APITransactionController>();
```

But the variable controller returns null.

Any Ideas how I can get around this?
Any other suggestions?  Maybe i'm going about this the wrong way....

Comment: Is it define as PUBLIC class APITransactionController ? with a public constructor ?

Comment: constructor was private.  let me make it public and try this again...

Comment: And that was the problem.  Thank you Mate.

Comment: Great! I'm added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check:

- Is it define as PUBLIC class APITransactionController ?
- Has it a public constructor ?